# Speeding up update with custom function in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a function, that checks if input ISBN code is valid or not, according to the wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit):

```
create or replace FUNCTION fn_isbn_valid (in_isbn IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 
    IS
      l_isbn VARCHAR2(14);
      l_last_digit NUMBER(1);
      l_checksum NUMBER;

    BEGIN
      l_isbn := LPAD(in_isbn, 14, 0);
      l_last_digit := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(l_isbn, -1, 1));

      l_checksum := 
      ((10 - 
      ((
        3 * (
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 1, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 3, 1)) +
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 5, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 7, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 9, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 11, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 13, 1)))
        + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 2, 1)) +
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 4, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 6, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 8, 1)) + 
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 10, 1)) +
          TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(L_isbn, 12, 1))   

      )mod 10 )) mod 10 ) ;  

      IF (l_checksum = l_last_digit) THEN
        RETURN 'Y';
      ELSE 
        RETURN 'N';
      END IF;  

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
        RETURN 'N';

    END fn_isbn_valid;
```

Then I have to use this function, to update an indicator column in my table:

```
    update my_table
        set isbn_valid_ind = 'N'
        where fn_isbn_valid(isbn) = 'N';
```

For a 100k rows table with 20k rows with invalid ISBN numbers update takes about 10 seconds.

Any hints or advice how could I speed up the process?
Thanks.

Comment: How often is this updated expected to be run? If it was something that was done every second or that the user was waiting on, 10 seconds would be quite a long time to have to wait. However, updating the table seems like an overnight/weekly task and 10 seconds is unlikely to hold things up. It's not necessarily a case of "can I speed this up?", but "should I speed this up?". However, a quick thing you could do is to add an additional predicate of `nvl(isbn_valid_ind, 'Y') != 'N'`, so that you're only updating rows that aren't correct.

Comment: (another option would be to incorporate the function logic directly into the sql statement itself, so that you're not having to do a context switch from SQL to PL/SQL for each row in the table, but I'd only go down that route if I really had to, in this instance).

Comment: I'd have to agree here.  Most of your time is probably spent on running the function itself 100K times.  If the value is valid, then mark the row as such.  Then you can exclude those going forward and you will execute the function fewer times on subsequent iterations.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  If you're using 12c it might be possible to call the function in a more efficient way using a `WITH` clause.

Comment: If you are on Oracle 12c you could also look at [`pragma udf`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/udf_pragma.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I am using oracle 11g 2.
It is not an overnight task, It is performed when user performs kind of specific load operation, so I would like to speed it up a little bit, not to make user wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do need to speed things up, then calculating the check digit as part of the SQL, rather than a separate function could be the way to do it, e.g.:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    isbn_valid_ind = 'N'
WHERE  CASE WHEN substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), -1) = mod(10 - MOD (3 * (to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 1, 1)) +
                                                                    to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 3, 1)) +
                                                                    to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 5, 1)) +
                                                                    to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 7, 1)) +
                                                                    to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 9, 1)) +
                                                                    to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 11, 1)) +
                                                                    to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 13, 1)))
                                                                 + to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 2, 1)) +
                                                                   to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 4, 1)) +
                                                                   to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 6, 1)) +
                                                                   to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 8, 1)) +
                                                                   to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 10, 1)) +
                                                                   to_number(substr(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), 12, 1)), 10), 10)
                 THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
       END = 'N';
```

N.B. I have taken the logic as presented in your question and modified it slightly (N MOD M is a PL/SQL construct; you'd need to use the MOD(N, M) function instead). If your logic has since changed, hopefully this will still give you an idea of how to incorporate the logic directly into your update statement.

Also, you could use the case statement to generate a virtual column (which would remove the need to do an update statement after the load has taken place), but this may slow down select statements that query that column. Hopefully, that column isn't used except to correct data, so a virtual column might be a viable alternative for you.

Comment: Do you have data to show ho much time is being taken by the function. Are you looking to speed up the right thing? For example, how long would an update of the same 20k rows take, without calling the function? Can you get an execution plan?

Comment: @BobC those comments would be better placed on the question rather than my answer, IMHO.

Comment: @BobC: sometimes they are not unique. I will provide execution plan (or an actual test) in few minutes.

Comment: @Boneist I see 2 problems with Your code:
1) 10 - MOD(10, 10) = 10, so it isn't equal to zero -> that's why I used second MOD

Comment: @IgnacyJakowiecki ah yeah. Good point; obviously I was having a brain-fart when I "fixed" that! Duh...

Comment: @Boneist: 
2) I don't understand the end of CASE, why returning some 'Y' and 'N', what will be finally in WHERE clause?

Comment: @IgnacyJakowiecki The CASE expression contains the logic that was previously in your function. If you notice, the CASE is doing "if the last digit of the isbn number is the same as the expected check digit, then return 'Y', otherwise return 'N'. We then check the output of the CASE expression and only display the row if it returns an 'N' (i.e. `where case .... end = 'N'`)

Comment: @Boneist, Ah, the very last comparison confused me. Now I understand. Nevertheless, trying to update Your way (even if adding TO_NUMBER before substringing the last digit) produces an ORA- 01722 INVALID NUMBER. Don't know why.
EDIT: Strange, it started working, will come back with an update on this.

Comment: @IgnacyJakowiecki I copied the logic of your function; if your isbn column has hyphens (as mentioned in comments by other people), you'll need to strip those out when doing the `SUBSTR`s. Also of note; I assumed that when you said the users were loading data into the table before updating it, that the table was empty. If that's not the case, then I would advise adding an extra predicate of `and isbn_valid_ind is null` - assuming, of course, that the column isn't prepopulated by the load.

Comment: @Boneist Your answer is really helpful, and really speeds up the thing. But maybe you have a hint, how to flag with "N" codes that really are not good, e.g when data was ETLd wrong into the database, and I end up with a value like: 13E+12? I hope that You get the point - in my function I could use the exception, but how to deal with it in clean SQL?

Comment: You'd need an additional when clause at the top of your case expression, something along the lines of `WHEN TRANSLATE(isbn, 'A01234567890-', 'A') IS NOT NULL THEN 'N'`. (I'm assuming here that your isbn field is populated by digits and hyphens.) By putting this at the top of the case expression, you can rely on the case short-circuiting to not process the `to_number()`s for isbns that don't consist of digits and hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this as an answer, just so I can format, but I'm really trying to elaborate on the comments I have made.

I have a "bigemp" table, 1.8M rows.

20% of the rows have a value of JOB = 'TEST'

If I run a straight SQL statement:

```
 update bigemp
  2  set ename = lower(ename)
  3  where job = 'TEST'
  4  /

367001 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:22.94
```

Now I have a function:

```
create or replace function is_valid( empno in number ) return varchar2
is
begin
  if mod( empno, 5 ) = 0
  then
    return 'N';
  else
    return 'Y';
  end if;
end;
```

Now I run what is essentially the same SQL statement, using the function:

```
SQL> update bigemp
  2  set ename = upper(ename)
  3  where is_valid( empno ) = 'N'
  4  /

367001 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:23.99
```

So both statements take ~ 23 seconds. So the the problem is not one of "speeding up the function".

So the moral is, look to see where the time is being spent.

Comment: Very true Bob.  But "help me speed up the function" is a challenge most of us can't resist. Esp because we can show how clever we all are ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to update only rows that need to be tested :

```
update my_table
set isbn_valid_ind = 'N'
where isbn_valid_ind != 'N'
and fn_isbn_valid(isbn) = 'N';
```

Another solution could be to initialize the field with NULL value, then update only rows that need to be tested :

```
update my_table 
set isbn_valid_ind = fn_isbn_valid(isbn) 
where isbn_valid_ind is null;
```

But i don't know if your job allow this...

Comment: Removing superfluous calls is a good idea, but in this case you would only see significant speed-up if the majority of ISBN in the table were invalid.

Comment: You are right Twinkles. The solution could be to initialize the field with `NULL` value, then update only rows that need to be tested : `update my_table set isbn_valid_ind = fn_isbn_valid(isbn) where isbn_valid_ind is null;`... but i don't know if the job allow this.

Comment: The real question: why is a runtime of 10 seconds a big deal? I have the feeling there is some unwise design decision at another level.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create a function like this (perhaps my version is faster than yours, please test):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CheckSum_ISBN(isbn IN NUMBER) RETURN INTEGER DETERMINISTIC IS
    res INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MOD(SUM((1+2*MOD(LEVEL,2)) * SUBSTR(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), LEVEL, 1)), 10)
    INTO res
    FROM dual  
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 14;
    RETURN res;
END CheckSum_ISBN;
```

Then you can add a virtual column to your table, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (CHECK_SUM INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CheckSum_ISBN(ISBN) ) VIRTUAL);
```

If needed you can create an index on this column in the same way as adding an index to a normal column.

```
CREATE INDEX ind_isbn_checksum ON my_table (CHECK_SUM);
```

Then it should be fairly quick to validate your numbers:

```
select *
from my_table
where CHECK_SUM <> to_number(substr(isbn,-1));
```

resp.

```
update my_table
set isbn_valid_ind = 'N'
where CHECK_SUM <> to_number(substr(isbn,-1));
```

Of course, you can do it also in one step:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CheckSum_ISBN(isbn IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC IS
    res VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
    SELECT 
       CASE WHEN
         MOD(SUM((1+2*MOD(LEVEL,2)) * SUBSTR(LPAD(isbn, 14, 0), LEVEL, 1)), 10) = TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(isbn, -1)) THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
       END 
    INTO res
    FROM dual  
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 14;
    RETURN res;
END CheckSum_ISBN;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, I messed up with ISBN numbers: I need to validate GTIN numbers only [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Trade_Item_Number, thus your function returns not true values.

Comment: My function should return the same values as your function. In this case your demonstration code is also wrong. Anyway, the main important point is to create a virtual column where you can put an index on.

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't seem to work with older 10 digit ISBNs, or take care of dashes in input.  I would make deterministic as well as make parallel enabled, and make it work for both 10 and 13 digit ISBNs.  Something like:

```
create or replace FUNCTION fn_isbn_valid (in_isbn IN VARCHAR2) 
  RETURN VARCHAR2 
  deterministic
  parallel_enable
AS
      l_isbn VARCHAR2(20);
      l_num number;
BEGIN
      l_isbn := replace(in_isbn, '-','');
      if (length(l_isbn) = 10) then
        l_num := (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 1, 1))*10)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 2, 1))*9)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 3, 1))*8)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 4, 1))*7)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 5, 1))*6)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 6, 1))*5)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 7, 1))*4)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 8, 1))*3)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 9, 1))*2)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 10, 1))*1);
        if ((l_num mod 11) = 0) then
                return 'Y';
        else 
            return 'N'; 
        end if;
      elsif (length(l_isbn) = 13) then
        l_num := (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 1, 1))*1)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 2, 1))*3)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 3, 1))*1)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 4, 1))*3)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 5, 1))*1)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 6, 1))*3)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 7, 1))*1)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 8, 1))*3)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 9, 1))*1)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 10, 1))*3)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 11, 1))*1)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 12, 1))*3)+
            (to_number(substr(l_isbn, 13, 1))*1);
        if ((l_num mod 10) = 0) then
                return 'Y';
        else 
            return 'N'; 
        end if;
      else
        return 'N';
      end if;

EXCEPTION
      WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
        RETURN 'N';

END fn_isbn_valid;
```

For example:

```
SQL> --13 digit
SQL> select fn_isbn_valid('9780306406157') from dual

FN_ISBN_VALID('9780306406157')                                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Y                                                                               
1 row selected.
SQL> select fn_isbn_valid('978-0-306-40615-7') from dual

FN_ISBN_VALID('978-0-306-40615-7')                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Y                                                                               
1 row selected.
SQL> -- 10 digit
SQL> select fn_isbn_valid('0-306-40615-2') from dual

FN_ISBN_VALID('0-306-40615-2')                                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Y                                                                               
1 row selected.
SQL> select fn_isbn_valid('0306406152') from dual

FN_ISBN_VALID('0306406152')                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Y                                                                               
1 row selected.
```

You could now use parallel DML using this function in an update statement as well.

A DML example:

```
SQL> create table test_isbn
(id number,
isbn varchar2(20),
is_valid char(1)
)
Table created.

SQL> insert into test_isbn(id, isbn)
select level as id, lpad(to_char(trunc(dbms_random.value(100000000,9999999999))), 10, 0) as isbn
from dual
connect by level <= 1000000
1000000 rows created.

SQL> commit
Commit complete.

SQL> --test without parallel dml
SQL> set timing on
SQL> update test_isbn
set is_valid = fn_isbn_valid(isbn)
1000000 rows updated.
**Elapsed: 00:00:11.55**

SQL> commit
Commit complete.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.05

SQL> --test with parallel dml
SQL> alter session enable parallel dml
Session altered.
Elapsed: 00:00:01.21

SQL> update /*+ parallel ti(10) */ test_isbn ti
set is_valid = fn_isbn_valid(isbn)
1000000 rows updated.
**Elapsed: 00:00:06.38**

SQL> commit
Commit complete.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
```

Comment: Hi tbone. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I messed up with ISBN usage - I need to check GTIN numbers [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Trade_Item_Number 
I know that Your function helps in checking other lengths of codes, but mine works there as well. So, would Your function speed up things?

Comment: Hi @IgnacyJakowiecki , your function does not work with 10 digit ISBNs (running: select fn_isbn_valid('0306406152') from dual; from your version returns 'N' and it should return 'Y').  Anyway, to speed things up for the updates (btw, 10 seconds is not bad at all considering), you can try to run parallel DML.  I'll update with a simple example